# Bonjour - Difference Between Clients and Servers?

Tags: iphone, client, bonjour

I have my iDevices doing some basic messaging via Bonjour and I am ready to move on to the next step.

Is there a difference between what a Server and Client device can do? From what I have seen so far, I can send messages from a Server to a Client and from a Client to a Server - so does it matter which device is serving which role?

Comment: bonjour is just for service discovery and has nothing to do with client-server-messaging !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bonjour is peer-to-peer, so there is no client or server.  It may be that the Bonjour sample you're working from happens to call the first instance to start broadcasting the "server" and the first instance to connect the "client", but this is just an arbitrary convention.